# Creating a .png file in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, png

So here is my code:

```
@echo off
set WAL=wallpaper.txt
echo ‰PNG >> %WAL%
echo  >> %WAL%
echo     >> %WAL%
echo IHDR   I      ZòRã     pHYs  Ä  Ä•+  iIDATX…í—­®â@Çÿws áÈî Qh’TµO@RU[GÕ¸6!iUÈ…ìŒÅ…jæ >> %WAL%
echo véÉL/_eÙÝ\²?5Ó9_™žö£ßïÿÄnòã_ðøÔ7Ûí–e]œÏçX¯×­DQ„^¯‡Édrñ<I0Æ0ZÛþ[—¤*¥|úbÚàºîµÿ >> %WAL%
echo >ï‹˜èÙV–¥‘!RJZçyŽN§Û¶é¬)˜™Æ9GÇHÓŽãžëºd[)e¼Ì$IÈGóìRexž!„¡ÀX7iÕ“²,CY–°m›ŒFQDÁJ)éÌ÷}¸®‹<ÏIçZÉ5‡°mžçÁ¶mH)i­ûŒ¢UU]G)Ev€sËB Š"0ÆH/ÏsdYv5ž‡3‰sÆ9€Ýn‡ñxL{ÆØ£æn†! @¥6› >> %WAL%
echo „ €¢(Ðét  ¾ïzeYÒ™eY8†n· Øl6¤·Z­Ç18çäG§u¹Åqlì•R Î½¥Î&àvúþ.z 5KJ/Ë^¯àü‚-ËÂñx$9Çq¨¤ïÑú’êš¾DÝ„“$A–e—×³Ôå¯ûÕaŒÑ¥åyn¡4M±X,òópOB ,KÌf³»²UUÑút:]ý¬xº/={c˜ÏçF¬)ŠÂh÷h•I“ÉÛíÖ˜bõôi¦}ðb±€ã8R’ì«ÃqS<z\ËåA zVgïûFk ¾NFwý-i~çM§SAðT¯|ËßÎ9 `¿ßÓ³n·KC¦-­÷w@4M¿Lâg'îÛ–Û+yËr{5¿ ÇË<ÐÉ•~    IEND®B`‚ >> %WAL%
pause
ren C:\Users\Moi\Desktop\test\wallpaper.txt wallpaper.png
pause
exit
```

What it does is it writes something into a text file and then converts it to a .png
(the text is what I get when I convert a .png to a .txt)

But it only writes

```
‰PNG
```

in the file and doesn't convert it to a .png

Is there another way to do it? Am I doing it wrong? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Search for topic "How to keep binary data in batch file and write into a file"

Comment: Unless you are using [codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage) (by `chcp 437`), many extended characters may become converted to something else. Besides that, you won't be able to echo out null-bytes. So a batch file is probably the worst choice to create a binary file…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work, because `echo` will append a `CRLF` at each end of line, and won't tolerate control characters globally.

The "good" method, with only native tools, is:

**Encoding image to batch:**

- Using Powershell, encode your file (the original image, in your case) in Base64.
- Split the B64 file into lines of maximum 4096 characters.
- Assign that to consecutive variables in your batch.

**Decoding image to disk:**

- Do an `echo` of all previously encoded variables in a temporary file (i.e. in `%TEMP%` folder).
- Using Powershell, convert the B64 file to a binary file.
- Delete temporary B64 file.
- Do what you want with the binary file.

**Reference:**
[Base64 encoding/decoding with Powershell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/base64-encodedecode-a-string/)

Comment: You can also use `certutil -encode` for most images instead if you don't want to make a hybrid script.

Comment: @SomethingDark Script is not really hybrid: that's a single call to `powershell`, a one-liner. Nothing more than what `certutil` would do: you wouldn't call script "hybrid" if it calls a standard Windows executable, so it isn't different with calling one-liner Powershell. The annoying part remains to encode/split/reassemble the file in Base64.